# How exactly do "start of turn" affects trigger

Tags: android-netrunner

This came up in a casual game with a friend last night. He is the runner with an economy based upon the [The Supplier](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=supplier&sort=set&view=list&_locale=en). One turn he hosted a [Data Folding](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07055) on it. At the start of his turn the "start of turn" effects trigger, and since it is his turn he picks the order. He claimed he could have the supplier resolve first, and then still get the money off the newly in play Data Folding. This didn't seem right to me as Data Folding wasn't in play when the "start of turn" effects triggered.

Who is correct?

What about a similar situation. He already has a data folding in play and wants to use the "start of turn" credit from it to pay for something else already hosted on the supplier. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the start of turn triggers happen at 1.2 every card *currently* in play which has a start of turn trigger tries to trigger. Since it's the runner's turn, their effects go first. The runner can choose the order of their own effects, so you can gain a credit from data folding, and then use that credit to pay to install something off The Supplier.

What you cannot do is install something off The Supplier / Personal Workshop and then have that newly installed card trigger a start of turn ability; it wasn't in play for the start of turn signal, and so has missed it's chance.

So you are correct, and the Data Folding wouldn't have given him any money for that turn.

Comment: This is correct. However there is one other complication. Cards that have a 'At the start of your turn...' trigger which are trashed before they are resolved do not resolve. For example if you have Wyldside and Aesop's pawnshop in play you may resolve them in either order - draw 2 cards and lose a click, then sell Wyldside to Aesop for 3 creds or sell Wyldeside to Aesop before it resolves. Yes, you can use the credit from Data Folding for paying for subsequent Supplier installs.